# How do I run Rails CLI commands for a remote database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a generator API and a main API and i want to delete the users of the main API database...can i run rails db:setup for this remote database?
i've searched alot about this and read many articles including rails guide but yet found nothing.

i tried to get all users and then delete them according to their id but it didn't work. so i want to use rails db:setup to keep only the first user and delete the others

**seed.rb (in remote API)**

```
User.create!(name: "joe", contact_email: "admin@lola.com", password: "123123", is_lola_admin: true)
```

Comment: What do you mean, "it didn't work"?

Comment: it didn't connect to the remote database and delete users

Comment: A rails app connects to whatever it finds in database.yml. So you can just change connection parameters there and try again. This is the easiest way, I think.

Comment: ok i'll try again ...thanks alot